# asp.net wizard control to create registration from

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

Sir Am New to Asp.net What is Asp.net Wizard Control and how it is use to create the registration as steps please any one help me i want complete details of wizard control and how to develop registration from using wizard and how to store data from Wizard to SqlServer 2005 please help me......

Comment: what do you need to do in the new step? in my case I have added new steps when I have wanted to add roles, for example. If all you need is to create a user, you would not need to create extra steps.

Comment: am developing a health project in first step i want doctor personal details and in second step i want clinic details and i want to store personal details in one table and clinic timings details in one another table how can i acheive it ........ plese tell in detail

Comment: Are you sure that what you need is the createuserwizard? If I were you I would create the clinic data separately since it seems to be a N:1 relation between Doctor and Clinic

Comment: ya sir  please tell me the solution

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following post:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx

It will give you a clear idea about how the createuserwizard works and its relation with the database by using asp.net membership.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This post from Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx) has several useful links regarding this topic; in particular, a [link to a video](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/3/6/836dd5f8-fa92-499f-8219-0d326f13bf18/hilo_contact_final.wmv) demonstrating exactly what you are trying to accomplish.